# Email Invalid > Need user to stay on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, validation, email, input

I created an web form that captures users email addresses. I have set up the conditions that need to be met in order for a user to be able to submit their email address and I am able to successfully return error messages.

However, if a user produces inputs an invalid code, they are still directed to the next screen after they close out the error.

HTML:

```
        <form class="watch-films" onsubmit="location.href='thankYou_watch.html'">
            <p class="paid_in_full">Email</p>
            <input class="field2" name="viewerEmail" id="viewerEmail" placeholder="youremail@example.com" required>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="button_done" value="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Javascript:

```
const watchForm = document.querySelector('.watch-films'); 
const feedback = document.querySelector('.feedback'); 
const viewerEmailPattern = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/; 


watchForm.addEventListener('submit', e=> {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    //validation
    const viewerEmail = watchForm.viewerEmail.value; 

    if(viewerEmailPattern.test(viewerEmail)){
      return (true)
    } else {
      alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
      return (false); 
    }

    console.log(watchForm.viewerEmail.value);
});
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Just move `location.href='thankYou_watch.html'` into your listener function, instead of returning true.

Comment: Where in the event listener can I place this? Thank you for the response!

Comment: Just use this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/hmqw31bx/ (note the form's `action` attribute that should point to the backend script that processes the form)

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have a submit event handler that redirects the browser to the thank-you page no matter what the result of the *other* submit event handler is.

> ```
> onsubmit="location.href='thankYou_watch.html'"
> ```

Since it redirects, it will stop the data from being submitted so you won't collect the email address.

Get rid of it entirely.

Have the server-side process that reads the submitted form data generate the thank-you page instead.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Quentin. I removed the submit event handler like you advised and tried to add it to my javascript, probably not correct:
`    if(viewerEmailPattern.test(viewerEmail)){
      return (true);
      window.location.href="thankYou_watch.html"; 
    } else {
      alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
      return (false); 
    }`

Correct inputted emails are not logging to the console and the page does not redirect. Errors are still showing up tho!

Comment: Think about what `return` does … and I said to move the `location` stuff entirely. If you want to collect the email address then you have to actually let the form submit to a server side process.